# How can i stop playing a song when another song start playing in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

Hello everyone i a listview with items in it. The moment you click on a item you hear a song but if you click on another item the first song doesn't stop it plays two songs at the same time how can i stop the first song if i click the second song or stop the second one if i click the first song

my code

```
private MediaPlayer mp;

  final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details));


        // When the user clicks on the ListItem
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final Songs titel = (titel) o;



                // get the club song from the arraylist
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(a.getContext(), titel.getClubLied());
                mp.start();

               mp.stop();
        });






 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mp.stop();
                return  true;
            }
        });
```

How can i fix this i used start and stop so the moment other song starts it stops but this doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `release` your mediaplayer to stop the mediaplayer like below:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final Songs titel = (titel) o;

            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
            }

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(a.getContext(), titel.getClubLied());
            mp.start();
    });
```

Comment: Bro thank you after 3 minutes i can accept it as a good answer

Answer (score 1):

you can check if MediaPlayer is playing then stop or release it first then play new song like that

```
           if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                 mp.stop();
                 mp.reset();
                 mp.release();
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(a.getContext(), titel.getClubLied());
            mp.start();
```

Hope its work;

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `MediaPlayer` as static so that only 1 item runs at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating mediaplayer in on setOnItemClickListener so whenever you click item it creates new mediaplayer so previous one is play continue so create media player outside the setOnItemClickListener than pass only song data..

```
private MediaPlayer mp;

  final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details));

mp = new MediaPlayer();
        // When the user clicks on the ListItem
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final Songs titel = (titel) o;



                // get the club song from the arraylist
        mp.reset()
        mp.setDataSource(a.getContext(), uri);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();


        });






 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mp.stop();
                return  true;
            }
        });
```